# Search Site People's Directory using search query REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to get **all the users** from the local people directory and display it.
If I type this in the browser, I see all the data I need.
If I use this in my code and compile it in spfx it does not work.
may I know what is the fix ?

My search query

```
 qurl="/_api/search/query?querytext=''&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&rowlimit=60";
```

- The code

```
private  getUser(){
 var qurl;

               qurl="/_api/search/query?querytext=''&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&rowlimit=60";
   const opt: ISPHttpClientOptions = { headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
     }};
   this.props.SPHttpClient.get(this.props.pagecontext.web.absoluteUrl + qurl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,opt)
   .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => { debugger;
       response.json().then((json: any) => { debugger;
        for(let i=0;i<json.value.length;i++){debugger; // json.value cannot read property , .value undefined


          this.ppl.push({
            name:json.value[i].PreferredName,
            jobtitle:json.value[i].JobTitle,
            workemail:json.value[i].WorkEmail,
            pictureurl:json.value[i].PictureURL,

          });
// codes continue...
```

I found that its a query so i must use

```
this.props.spHttpClient.get(url, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, opt).then(response=>{
            response.json().then(res=>{

                let result = res.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows;
```

I can get

```
0: {Key: "RowLimit", Value: "60", ValueType: "Edm.Int32"}
1: {Key: "SourceId", Value: "b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31", ValueType: "Edm.Guid"}
2: {Key: "CorrelationId", Value: "e9c7339f-e0fd-b000-e515-bff3355a8995", ValueType: "Edm.Guid"}
3: {Key: "EnableInterleaving", Value: "true", ValueType: "Edm.Boolean"}
4: {Key: "IsMissingUnifiedGroups", Value: "false", ValueType: "Edm.Boolean"}
5: {Key: "Constellation", Value: "i4302D", ValueType: "Edm.String"}
6: {Key: "MultiGeoSearchStatus", Value: "Full", ValueType: "Edm.String"}
7: {Key: "IsPartial", Value: "false", ValueType: "Edm.Boolean"}
8: {Key: "InternalRequestId", Value: "fa2dfdc9-e705-40e3-a99e-468cedbe7d4a", ValueType: "Edm.String"}
9: {Key: "SerializedQuery", Value: "<Query Culture="en-US" EnableStemming="True" Enabl…070cd" KeywordType="True" HiddenConstraints="" />", ValueType: "Edm.String"}
length: 10
```

but it no primary data result.
if I append the link it shows in the browser
What is the solution?

[image: rest-api-search-query]

Using V3 ODATAVERSION SAME RESULTS.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try change the OData version on rest api call.the Search REST API doesn't accept OData v4. Example:

```
let config: SPHttpClientConfiguration = new SPHttpClientConfiguration({
    defaultODataVersion: ODataVersion.v3
});

this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + searchUrl, config, { headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;charset=utf-8" } }).then((response) => {
```

Comment: thanks shahul, but no luck same results. Nothing in PrimaryResults

Comment: 1) Your "querytext" seems empty "/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&rowlimit=60", Can you please update the rest endpioint from above and try

Comment: oh .............. thanks so much. It finally worked..
may I know how did you which documents says REST API don't accept v4?

Comment: @RandomI.T - this is the github issue that says Search Rest API does not support OData v4(https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3960#issuecomment-492846382)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change ODataVersion to 3
2. for querytext use * for selct all/ wildcard

```
qurl="/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&rowlimit=60";
const opt: ISPHttpClientOptions = { headers: {
  Accept: "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;charset=utf-8"
 }};
 let config: SPHttpClientConfiguration = new SPHttpClientConfiguration({
  defaultODataVersion: ODataVersion.v3
});
this.props.SPHttpClient.get(this.props.pagecontext.web.absoluteUrl + qurl,config ,opt).then((response) => {
    response.json().then(res => { debugger;
      let result=res.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.Cells;
```